# jQuery not showing in Phonegap on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I have jQuery being called on an Android app that is using Phonegap. Going through just the internet, my jQuery is being read as expected.

My config file has:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.bunchofus.basicphonegap" version="1.0.0"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

<access origin="*" />
```

My HTML and jQuery is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bunch.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#topbar').load('http://www.bunchofus.com/app/topbar.php');  
jQuery('#posts').load('http://www.bunchofus.com/app/recentposts.php');
});
</script>

</head>      
<body>
<div id="topbar">

</div>
<div id="posts">

</div>
</body>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

***Update****

I now have it working. On the config file, I needed to add:

gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />

My HTML is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);    
function onDeviceReady() {
$('#posts').load('http://www.bunchofus.com/app/recentposts.php');
};  
</script>
```

Whether it is perfectly correct or not, it is working!

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: don't use jquery mobile CDN, download their js and css and use it locally

Comment: Also use the Cordova/Phonegap deviceready event before doing anything.

Comment: I agree with jcesarmobile and simon . You also need to implement the `whitelist` [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md) -- This should also help. [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'll give these a shot.